# vim: why whitespace character \s not working in bracket expression, but \n do

Tags: regex, vim

for example, put /\s in vim will match any whitespace, but /[\s] does not.

I thought it's because backslash escapes are not allowed in bracket expression as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended, but then I tested /[\n] which correctly match the end-of-line.

Why is this behavior? Is there any document describe this behavior?

Comment: in pcre, it's allowed. that would be possibly design decision. to explain that, i would say `\s` is a character set itself, and it's semantically weird to have a set inside of a set, while `\n` is a character, which is ok. opinion based though. btw, re in vim is in its own flavor, it's not posix re or extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim uses its own brand of regular expression syntax which is AFAIK not documented on Wikipedia. Like everything Vim, it's documented in Vim itself, `:help pattern`, and there is [a good introduction](http://vimregex.com/) online too.

Collections contain single characters. Since `\s` is itself a collection of whitespace characters and not a single character it can't be contained in another collection. If you want to include whitespace characters in a collection, you'll have to include them one-by-one: `[ \t]`.

`[\n]` works because `\n` is a single character.

```
:help pattern
:help /[]
:help /[\n]
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason, Vim could perfectly add all characters to the collation. My guess is, this is  done for convenience. Furthermore `[literal \n]` would not be easy to parse as regular expression and therefore it was added. The rest was probably added as convenient abbreviaions for hard to type chars.